# RobotFramework can't detect SeleniumLibrary

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I recently downloaded an SSHLibrary to run tests for RobotFramework and my previously compiling code is now unable to detect any RobotKeywords from the Selenium and Database libraries.

Also noting that I am using PyDev on Eclipse, not RIDE.

Here are some of the errors being shown:

```
[ ERROR ] Adding keyword 'add_cookie' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
[ ERROR ] Adding keyword 'add_location_strategy' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
[ ERROR ] Adding keyword 'alert_should_be_present' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
[ ERROR ] Adding keyword 'alert_should_not_be_present' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
[ ERROR ] Adding keyword 'capture_element_screenshot' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
[ ERROR ] Adding keyword 'capture_page_screenshot' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
[ ERROR ] Adding keyword 'click_button' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
[ ERROR ] Adding keyword 'click_element' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
[ ERROR ] Adding keyword 'click_image' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
[ ERROR ] Adding keyword 'click_link' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
[ ERROR ] Adding keyword 'create_webdriver' to library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: Return value must be list of strings.
```

Comment: Do the errors come when you run the test, or when you open a file in Eclipse?

Comment: Did you update Python version by any chance? If you did its probably trying to open the packages in the new version and the packages are in the old version file paths.